I am making a discord bot but it won't start up when I run the 'startup.js' file
Can someone help me start up my bot? its startup code looks something like this
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
client.once(Events.ClientReady, readyClient => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${readyClient.user.tag}`);
});
client.login(bot token here);

I started the code expecting my bot to just appear with an online presence, I don't know if it started up with an offline presence or if it just didn't start up

are you following the instructions at discordjs.guide by any chance?

Describe in detail how you start up the bot, step-by-step, what actions you take.
